# Search function in c# console

Tags: c#, string, search, console

I am making a console project in `c#` to make a search function. It will ask the name and check from array and find them to show the total balance amount.

How to make a function of search and use in other functions?

```
void total_bank_balance()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the name for check the total balance");
  name = Console.ReadLine();
  for ( int k = 0; k < b; k++ )
  {
    if ( customer_name[k] == name )
    {
      Console.WriteLine(customer_name[k] + " Your total bank balance is " + bank_balance[k]);
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("The Customer is not present in our database");
    }
  }
}
```

I'm searching manually, but I want to make a search function and use it in the total bank balance and when they search show his amount in bank.

Output should be like make a search function and use in total bank balance amount regarding use of code it should use code readability.

Comment: Your current code will say the customer isn't in the database every time through the loop when the name doesn't match until a match is found. You shouldn't print that message until after the loop if a match isn't found.

Comment: Please, edit your question and indicate more infomation about your arrays and the total balance for example. Add some samples of data.

Answer (score 1):

If this is more about code readability, here is my appraoch

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}

private List<Customer> CustomerList { get; set; }

void TotalBankBalance()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the name for check the total balance");
    string SearchTerm = Console.ReadLine();
    Customer SearchResult = CustomerList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == SearchTerm);

    if (SearchResult != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} your total bank balance is {1:C2}", SearchResult.Name, SearchResult.Balance);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Customer is not present in our database");
    }
}
```

1. Use a custom class for your customer
2. Maintain the customers in one list instead of separated with their balances
3. Personal taste but mixing up  snake_case and CamelCase hurts in my eyes
4. Shorten loops with `Linq`